# Monster respawning in Unepic

Tags: unepic

What triggers the standard monsters to respawn in Unepic?  I know that if you die, everything comes back, but I've noticed that after a while (even without dying) rooms that were once clear have their monsters back.

Is it based on play time or time since you were last in that room? Number of rooms visited?  Total number of monsters currently killed?

Answer (score 1):

On [this](https://kb.speeddemosarchive.com/Unepic/Mechanics_and_Glitches) page you cann see that Monsters are Respwaning after you reload the game:

> Saving and reloading the game has the following effects:
>
> All monsters respawn and reset to their default position.

I cant find any other mechanic that made respawn possible but they could be exist. It is not as detailed an answer i know but its a part of the answer.

Comment: I actually knew that, since dying just reloads your last save.  That's an interesting page, though.

Comment: Coudnt find more on the Net then this. The only thing i can think of, in conclusion with the reload, is that the game made some kind of chunks that load periodikly new, but i have no way to verify this - so no answer ^^

Comment: That does make the most sense, and it's how other games handle this type of thing.  But I'd hope for some type of details (like "It only stores the last 10 rooms" or something).  Thanks for trying!